# JS. XHR. Кодировка исходящего текста.

Tags: google-chrome, javascript, xmlhttprequest, chrome-extension

Доброго времени!

Есть некий сервер. Отвечает, принимает запросы. Пишу плагин к хрому. 
Уходящий русский текст приходит китайским.

Отправляю так:

```
function AddNewGroup(aName, aDesc) {

    var node = $("#Tree").dynatree("getActiveNode");
    if (node == null) {
        alert("Нет выбранной группы.");
        return;
    };
    var nkey = node.data.key;
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var d = {
        method : "POST",
        url : "http://" + getRQDomain() + "/addgroup",
        async : true
    };
    var params = 'Owner=' + nkey + '&Name=' + aName + '&Desc=' + aDesc;
    http.open(d.method, d.url, d.async);
    http.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    $("#load").css("display", "inline");
    $("#ServerStatus").text("Загрузка...");
    http.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (http.readyState == 4) {
            if (http.status == 200) {
                $("#load").css("display", "none");
                $("#ServerStatus").text("Готово.");
                $("#ServerStatus").css("color", "green");
                LoadTree();
            } else {
                $("#load").css("display", "none");
                $("#ServerStatus").text("Не отправить запрос");
                $("#ServerStatus").css("color", "red");
            };
        }
    };
    http.send(params);
};
```

Где aName, aDesc:

```
AddNewGroup($("#GrNameId").val(), $("#GrDescId").val());
```

Если отправляю русский текст, то на сервер приходят крикозябры. Как быть? На FF тот же самый плагин, и все нормально с исходящим русским текстом.

Можно как-то из XMLHttpRequest влиять на исходящие кодировки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно докам HTTP. В content-type дописал:

```
charset="UTF-8"
```

и все нормально стало.

**Проблема исчерпана.**